# ANR in XMPP Service

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, android-anr-dialog

I'm using Smack XMPP client in a custom service, and everything goes well ... until I had some reports of ANR from android market. 
I've been reading a lot of Threads of StackOverflow for finding what could be the reason. I also tried to read traces and dumpstate...
I finally think I've understood why is this happening and how I can reproduce it. It looks like some phone, like Galaxy S,
are more sensitive than others Motorola Milestone and HTC Wildfire (I have those 3 devices). When I load on purpose loads of apps, and come back
to my app, it is more likely to have ANR, and especially using maps.

My problem is, I have no idea how to deal with that, and how I can avoid to have ANR, 
for example a function saying "be careful dude, memory is almost full", and then you can delete the service (Even if I don't really want it...)

If you want traces or dump, just ask in comment but I guess it's more or less useless in my case.

Cheers !

Update; Here we Go, StackTrace :

```
11-24 17:20:25.357 I/am_anr  ( 2479): [22962,com.meetme.android.activities,48708,Executing service com.meetme.android.activities/com.meetme.android.service.XmppService]

------ VM TRACES AT LAST ANR (/data/anr/traces.txt: 2011-11-24 17:20:26) ------

DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8b0 self=0xcd30
  | sysTid=22962 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345017808
  | schedstat=( 20241984823 12130991031 35574 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x48000f68> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:146)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"DispatcherThread" prio=5 tid=14 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x48350d20 self=0x609528
  | sysTid=23150 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6329960
  | schedstat=( 482871 9604514 3 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4828e450> (a android.os.MessageQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:146)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:110)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)

"Timer-14" prio=5 tid=15 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4804a2f8 self=0x291818
  | sysTid=23147 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7785080
  | schedstat=( 232664 3847398 4 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4804a2f8> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:219)

"Timer-13" prio=5 tid=16 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4818f4b8 self=0x60d0d0
  | sysTid=23143 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8388112
  | schedstat=( 157746 13991968 4 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4818f4b8> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:219)

"Smack Listener Processor (1)" daemon prio=5 tid=26 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x482937b0 self=0x7e6290
  | sysTid=23140 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6353344
  | schedstat=( 1789199 14773003 12 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x482939e0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"Smack Keep Alive (1)" daemon prio=5 tid=25 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x482a50e0 self=0x7e7080
  | sysTid=23139 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8286656
  | schedstat=( 207789 1223315 3 )
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1306)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1286)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter$KeepAliveTask.run(PacketWriter.java:451)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"Smack Packet Reader (1)" daemon prio=5 tid=24 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x482003d8 self=0x7db9d8
  | sysTid=23138 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8239896
  | schedstat=( 8964691 15593096 48 )
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.readSocketImpl(Native Method)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(OSNetworkSystem.java:358)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:561)
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:88)
  at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:275)
  at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:338)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peek(KXmlParser.java:931)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:589)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:333)
  at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1385)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:368)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:76)

"Smack Packet Writer (1)" daemon prio=5 tid=21 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x48274808 self=0x800a18
  | sysTid=23137 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=8391512
  | schedstat=( 4035424 2055217 34 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x48274790> (a java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.nextPacket(PacketWriter.java:239)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.writePackets(PacketWriter.java:255)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter.access$000(PacketWriter.java:40)
  at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketWriter$1.run(PacketWriter.java:87)

"Timer-4" prio=5 tid=20 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x480d4220 self=0x7fffe0
  | sysTid=23123 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6557936
  | schedstat=( 174580 10994824 3 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x480d4220> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:219)

"Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=19 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x48172aa8 self=0x67dbe8
  | sysTid=23059 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=7217208
  | schedstat=( 61468336 98741186 263 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Timer-2" prio=5 tid=9 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x481cc450 self=0x5f92b8
  | sysTid=23044 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=6124424
  | schedstat=( 3747116 7045008 8 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x481cc450> (a java.util.Timer$TimerImpl)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:288)
  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:219)

"AsyncTask #5" prio=5 tid=13 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4810d888 self=0x2b7ad0
  | sysTid=22976 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2849808
  | schedstat=( 2703400040 4409206985 2479 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4810da80> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4810d6e0 self=0x2b5f20
  | sysTid=22975 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2842720
  | schedstat=( 2980400404 5043212188 12529 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4810d838> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=11 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4810d4a0 self=0x2b5318
  | sysTid=22974 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2842200
  | schedstat=( 2325671917 4252091750 5008 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x4810d5f8> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x481088d0 self=0x2b43b0
  | sysTid=22973 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2834960
  | schedstat=( 2162608466 3503692881 5444 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x48108a28> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"AsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4802d5a0 self=0x268df0
  | sysTid=22970 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=2712144
  | schedstat=( 2947433374 4855945812 6110 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x47ffb6f0> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1535)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:48)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:317)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:131)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1996)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:359)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1001)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)

"CacheManagerEraser" prio=5 tid=7 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x480375c0 self=0x24e3c0
  | sysTid=22968 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2416880
  | schedstat=( 159612334 51354720 52 )
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1306)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1286)
  at com.meetme.android.datamanager.CacheManager$1.run(CacheManager.java:178)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x48004cf8 self=0x13fa98
  | sysTid=22967 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1170896
  | schedstat=( 133957060 207385468 521 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=5 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x48001798 self=0x11ca00
  | sysTid=22966 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1164656
  | schedstat=( 132801475 181256274 516 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x47ffa2a0 self=0x123998
  | sysTid=22965 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1189920
  | schedstat=( 2230570974 894018700 22290 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x47ffa1e8 self=0x122698
  | sysTid=22964 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1271872
  | schedstat=( 60947251 71847193 19 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4524d7f0 self=0x11ce90
  | sysTid=22963 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1252504
  | schedstat=( 922251554 405119813 1365 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Given that an ANR gets called when the UI thread is blocked for 5 seconds or more: Search where you are doing expensive, long running calls in the UI-thread, e.g. network calls. You can use [strict mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) to diagnose the problem *([here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html) is a small introduction)*

Comment: thanks, but I need an API9 phone with the same problem to be able to use StrictMode. I'll try and I update this thread !

Comment: Just run it in a Api9+ emulator instance. Should throw you the relevant exceptions too. If these calls are present, they are always called on every phone. Some devices are probably just faster or their network connectivity is better so that everything finishes under 5 seconds as opposed to other devices. Which makes things also to seem somewhat random because the error doesn't show on the slightly faster ones.

Comment: OK, I tried with a HTC DesireHD , v2.3.3 and launched as much apps as I could, I'm trying to make my app suffer, but I can't get this ANR. Do you this the emulator can get one ? Because I never had it on emulator. Or maybe some advices to have ANR ? :)

Comment: hahaha, apparently I'm not alone to have this problem, I had an ANR from a service of another app

Comment: It's not about stressing the phone to the max. If you enabled strict mode it will detect the problematic calls, doesn't matter if the execute in 1ms or 1 hour. You will get a Force-Close, and if you look into the logcat then, you will see a exception that tells you exactly whats wrong where (e.g. a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`). So just enabled it as described in the docs and test all the functionality of your app through.

Comment: yup, I added the StrictMode in the onCreate of the service, and I didn't have an Exception.

Comment: stack traces would maybe be helpful here...